# GUI Figure Unplottable

Tags: matlab, plot

I created a plotting tool and its GUI.  The tool lets you create blank figures with a specific tag so that I can only plot to the figures generated by the tool.

In other words, when I plot things with the tool, the GUI 'figure' is not an option to select (it doesn't have the tag).  However, since it's still a figure, I can plot onto it from the command line.  If I'm not careful by creating a blank figure with 'figure' command in the command line, the 'plot' command will plot on the tool's GUI and I end up relaunch the tool.

Is there a way to render this GUI unplottable?  Matlab doesn't see it as the gcf so that 'plot' command will create a new blank figure to plot something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the GUI main figure's `HandleVisibilty`  property to `callback` depending on how you setup your GUI.  [See Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/preventing-access-to-figures-and-axes.html)

> HandleVisibility is a property of all graphics objects. It controls
>   the visibility of the object’s handle to three possible values:
>
> - on — You can obtain the object's handle with functions that return handles, such as (gcf, gca, gco, get, and findobj). This is the
>     default behavior.
> - callback — The object's handle is visible only within the workspace of a callback function.
> - off — The handle is hidden from all functions executing in the command window and in callback functions.

Comment: Thank you very much